# Regex for Decimal number not working in flutter TextFormField inputFormatters

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, regex-group

**The requirement for Regex:**

- Max length of the number is 12 character
- If there is a decimal point in number then the user can add a maximum of 4 digits after the decimal point and minimum 1 digit.
- Valid Inputs: - 222244445555, 22223333.3333, 5555.33, 1.2, 0.33, 11112222333.3
- InValid Inputs: 22., .11, 2222333344443,444445555544.,333344445.1234

I have tried to generate regex for the same on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) and it satisfied my requirements but when I applied the same for the flutter form TextFormField it not working.

**Regex:** `^[[0-9]{0,8}(\.[0-9]{1,4})?$|^[[0-9]{0,9}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$|^[[0-9]{0,10}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$|^[[0-9]{0,11}(\.[0-9]{1})?$|^[0-9]{0,12}`

**Flutter TextFieldCode:**

```
TextFormField(
   controller: _textEditingController,
   keyboardType:TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
   inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
          WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'^[[0-9]{0,8}(\.[0-9]{1,4})?$|^[[0-9]{0,9}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$|^[[0-9]{0,10}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$|^[[0-9]{0,11}(\.[0-9]{1})?$|^[0-9]{0,12}')),
   ],
),
```

Using the above code I am not able to type `dot(.)` inside the TextFormField.

**Note:** Users should not be able to enter the number more than one decimal point in the `TextFormField`.

Comment: check this : https://github.com/askNilesh/flutter_decimal_validator

Comment: @NileshRathod please check there are other points in the requirements. Your solution will not work in my case. I have already tried this type of solution.

Comment: Why would `333344445.1234` be invalid? Because it would be 13 digits?

Comment: @JvdV yes max length is 12 without or without decimal.

Comment: Ok, well I'm not familiar with `Flutter`, but maybe try [this](https://regex101.com/r/rYxesD/5) pattern?

Comment: @JvdV Yeah Your RE is correct but the main issues valid RE is not working in the flutter textFiled.  Btw thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Note that if you want to validate the whole input *sequence* you need to define a `validator: validateMyInput` and then implement the function:

```
String validateMyInput(String value) {
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'^(?=\D*(?:\d\D*){1,12}$)\d+(?:\.\d{1,4})?$');
    if (!regex.hasMatch(value))
      return 'Enter Valid Number';
    else
      return null;
  }
```

See more details at [*Form Validation in Flutter*](https://medium.com/@nitishk72/form-validation-in-flutter-d762fbc9212c).

The regex is

```
^(?=\D*(?:\d\D*){1,12}$)\d+(?:\.\d{1,4})?$
```

See [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/ozm1KS/1). **Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=\D*(?:\d\D*){1,12}$)` - one to twelve digits required in the string
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,4})?` - an optional sequence of a `.` and then 1, 2, 3 or 4 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Validator is fine What I want is the User can not type the invalid number in the input so If we can set some regex in ```inputFormatters``` then I think it works. In your given validator function I tired to enter 3.33.3 and ```textfiled``` takes this input. The requirement is After one decimal point User should be not able to enter any decimal point

Comment: @DhavalKansara So, you are talking about a *live input validation*. You should have indicated this in the question in the first place.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. I have added a note to the question.

Comment: @DhavalKansara Did it work for you finally with [`FilteringTextInputFormatter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter-class.html)? With, say, `^(?=\D*(?:\d\D*){1,12}$)\d+(?:\.\d{0,4})?$`?

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me!

```
inputFormaters:[FilteringTextInputFormater.allow(RegEx("[0-9.]"))]
```